# How to put Preinstalled UBUNTU Touch Image in usb

Tags: live-usb, tar, disk-image

I have an x86 tablet and I want to install Ubuntu touch on it
I downladed the tar.gz image at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/20150523/

but since its tar.gz I do not know what should I do with it please help, I am not very knowledgeable

FYI : I am on windows 8.1

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about installing the `tar.gz` file, but you can download an ISO image from here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-desktop-next/daily-live/current/. Note: these are unstable (as is the file you already downloaded) and could break easily.

The file you probably want is [this](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-desktop-next/daily-live/current/wily-desktop-amd64.iso). If your tablet isn't 64-bit, then download [this one](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-desktop-next/daily-live/current/wily-desktop-i386.iso). Burn it to a memory stick and boot to it from your tablet. You should then be able to run the installer from the live USB.

I recommend you don't do this at all if you're not sure, because these are development releases and could break; additionally, if something goes wrong, you might not know how to restore the tablet to how it previously was.

Comment: Hi thank you for the quick answer, I wanted to install a touch version ubuntu , and not the desktop version . Is there any iso image for ubuntu touch ? I tried but i could not find any, thanks!

Comment: Despite the name, this is the touch version

Comment: It has a UI designed for tablets, though it will eventually adapt to whatever device you install it on, including desktops, which is why it's named as the desktop image.

Comment: Hey there I installed ubuntu desktop but nothing happened not even an on screen keyboard

Comment: Yes, it's very unstable and might not work on everything. Maybe try the current version? It has some support for tablets, might work

Comment: The link here no longer works. I believe the new URL is http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/  but there's no listing for a 64-bit version for PCs at the moment. :-(

Comment: @tudor There *is* and i386 version which as we all know is x86. However, there is **no iso file** which is quite frustrating.