# Ubuntu touch on a usb stick

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, rufus

I'm trying to install Ubuntu touch on a USB stick, then plug it into a windows machine and just boot Ubuntu from there.

I have downloaded Rufus and now I'm trying to find an `.iso` of ubuntu touch.

I downloaded the files from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/vivid/daily-preinstalled/20170123/HEADER.html) but there was no `.iso`. I did find [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628875/how-to-put-preinstalled-ubuntu-touch-image-in-usb) but it hasn't helped.

Where could I find the `.iso`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no ISO file for Ubuntu Touch, Ubuntu Touch is not a standard distribution for PC. The image you downloaded is not a daily driver image of Ubuntu Touch it's purpose is to be used for Ubuntu Touch platform development.

If you want to do Ubuntu Touch platform development the best way to use that image is to use the [UBports Platform Development Kit](https://github.com/ubports/ubports-pdk).